# Windows Shell Script Default Folder

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, windows-10, sh

I'm trying to create a shell script for deploy a django application in Windows 10. I'm just at the beginning but what I want to do is:

- Create the directory C:\Software\MyApp;
- Clone the project from GitLab in C:\Software\MyApp;
- Install virtualenv in C:\Software\MyApp\py2_env;

So I wrote this script

```
# setup folser
cd C:\
mkdir C:\Software\MyApp
cd C:\Software\MyApp

# clone application
git clone https://gitlab.com/blablabla/Application.git

# virtualenv
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv C:\Software\EVARplanning\py2_env
C:\Software\EVARplanning\py2_env\Script\activate
```

I save it in a file called installation.sh that is in my Desktop folder. The problem is that when I double-click it, it create an "Application" and "SoftwareMyApppy2_env" folder in my Desktop (`C:\Users\<user>\Desktop`).
The strange thing is that if I open a terminal and copy/paste those commands one by one, they work perfectly...

Can you tell me what I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If I have to bet your desktop is not placed in drive `c:`. That means the batch file is not in drive `c:` so `cd c:\ ` or `cd c:\Software\MyApp` change the default directory for `c:` drive but does not change the current drive. I would try with `cd /d C:\ ` in your first line to force drive change

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately just have the `C:` drive. My Desktop is in `C:\Users\<user>\Desktop`. The strange thing is that if I open a terminal and copy/paste those commands one by one, they work perfectly...

Comment: path delimiter in Windows Batch is `\ ` (as you have it), but Shell uses `/` (as far as I know) and `\ ` is an escape character (the `\ ` is missing in `"SoftwareMyApppy2_env"`). Try either `/` or `\\ `  instead of `\ `